# Return initial data on subscribe event in django graphene subscriptions

Tags: websocket, graphql, subscription, django-channels, graphene-django

I'm trying to response to user on subscribe. By example, in a chatroom when an user connect to subscription, the subscription responses him with data (like a welcome message), but only to same user who just connect (no broadcast).

How can I do that? :(

Update: We resolve to use channels. DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs does not allow direct back messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this DjangoChannelsGraphQL example](https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs/blob/master/example/example.py#L197). Link points to the part which is there to avoid "user self-notifications" (avoid user being notified about his own actions). You can use the same trick to send notification only to the user who made the action, e.g. who just subscribed.

Modified `publish` handler could look like the following:

```py
def publish(self, info, chatroom=None):
    new_msg_chatroom = self["chatroom"]
    new_msg_text = self["text"]
    new_msg_sender = self["sender"]
    new_msg_is_greetings = self["is_greetings"]

    # Send greetings message only to the user who caused it.
    if new_msg_is_greetings:
        if (
            not info.context.user.is_authenticated
            or new_msg_sender != info.context.user.username
        ):
            return OnNewChatMessage.SKIP

    return OnNewChatMessage(
        chatroom=chatroom, text=new_msg_text, sender=new_msg_sender
    )
```

I did not test the code above, so there could be issues, but I think it illustrates the idea quite well.